# Postgres Jsonb aggregation

Tags: postgresql, json

I am trying to achieve following (Result Required) output from POSTGRES jsonb columns, but not getting desired result using "jsonb_agg" function.
I went through this postgres document https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html, but no luck here.
Also am not that good in json data in postgres, so please suggest good resource for json formatting related stuff for postgres.

| City | JColA | JColB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NY | [{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":20.12,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID2","name":"ID2_NAME","type":"ID2_TYPE","amount":11.55,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":5.45,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"1"},{"key":"key2","value":"2"},{"key":"key3","value":"3"}] |
| DC | [{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":1.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID3","name":"ID3_NAME","type":"ID3_TYPE","amount":1.2,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":1,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"1"},{"key":"key1","value":"2"},{"key":"key1","value":"3"}] |
| DL | [{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":1.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID2","name":"ID2_NAME","type":"ID2_TYPE","amount":1.2,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":1,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"2"},{"key":"key2","value":"2"},{"key":"key3","value":"4"}] |
| NY | [{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":4.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID2","name":"ID2_NAME","type":"ID2_TYPE","amount":2.2,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":6,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key4","value":"2"},{"key":"key2","value":"5"},{"key":"key2","value":"4"}] |
| DC | [{"id":"ID3","name":"ID3_NAME","type":"ID3_TYPE","amount":2.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID3","name":"ID3_NAME","type":"ID3_TYPE","amount":2.2,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":2,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"2"},{"key":"key2","value":"2"},{"key":"key3","value":"4"}] |

**Required Result**

| City | AggJSonColA | AggJsonColB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NY | [{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":30.07,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID2","name":"ID2_NAME","type":"ID2_TYPE","amount":13.75,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":6,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"1"},{"key":"key2","value":"11"},{"key":"key3","value":"3"}, {"key":"key4","value":"2"}] |
| DC | [{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":1.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID3","name":"ID3_NAME","type":"ID3_TYPE","amount":5.9,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":3,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"8"},{"key":"key2","value":"2"},{"key":"key3","value":"4"}] |
| DL | [{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":1.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID2","name":"ID2_NAME","type":"ID2_TYPE","amount":1.2,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":1,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"2"},{"key":"key2","value":"2"},{"key":"key3","value":"4"}] |

Comment: Sample data as `CREATE/INSERT` statements would help, as would your current attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to break out the arrays with `jsonb_to_recordset`, rebuild the objects using `jsonb_build_object`, and aggregate them back up with `jsonb_agg`

```sql
SELECT
  A.City,
  A.JColA,
  B.JColB
FROM (
    SELECT
      City,
      jsonb_agg(JColA) AS JColA
    FROM (
        SELECT
          t.City,
          json_build_object(
            'id', id,
            'name', name,
            'type', type,
            'amount', SUM(amount),
            'full_name', full_name
          ) AS JColA
        FROM YourTable t,
        LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(t.JColA)
          AS arr(id varchar(10), name varchar(100), type varchar(100), amount decimal (18,2), full_name varchar(100))
        GROUP BY
          t.City, arr.id, arr.name, arr.type, arr.full_name
    ) A
    GROUP BY
      City
) A
JOIN (
    SELECT
      City,
      jsonb_agg(JColB) AS JColB
    FROM (
        SELECT
          t.City,
          json_build_object(
            'key', "key",
            'value', SUM(value)
          ) AS JColB
        FROM YourTable t,
        LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(t.JColB)
          AS arr("key" varchar(10), value int)
        GROUP BY
          t.City, arr."key"
   ) B
    GROUP BY
      City  
) B ON B.City = A.City;
```

I feel it's easier to requery the original table again, however if you want to avoid that, you could first aggregate all the arrays together by `City`, break them back out and re-aggregate.

```
SELECT
  t.City,
  (
    SELECT
      jsonb_agg(JColA)
    FROM (
        SELECT
          json_build_object(
            'id', id,
            'name', name,
            'type', type,
            'amount', SUM(amount),
            'full_name', full_name
          ) AS JColA
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(t.JColA) AS outerArr,
        LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(outerArr)
          AS arr(id varchar(10), name varchar(100), type varchar(100), amount decimal (18,2), full_name varchar(100))
        GROUP BY
          arr.id, arr.name, arr.type, arr.full_name
    ) A
  ) AS JColA,
  (
    SELECT
      jsonb_agg(JColB)
    FROM (
        SELECT
          json_build_object(
            'key', "key",
            'value', SUM(arr.value)
          ) AS JColB
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(t.JColB) AS outerArr,
        LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(outerArr)
          AS arr("key" varchar(10), value int)
        GROUP BY
          arr."key"
     ) B
  ) AS JColB
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.City,
      jsonb_agg(JColA) AS JColA,
      jsonb_agg(JColB) AS JColB
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY
      t.City
) t;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=551a4f8ac2158ef6d4d07b493fd67d58)

Comment: +1 it's quite amazing to me how powerful Postgres is when it comes to slicing and dicing JSON and I also love this answer as an example of why one should AVOID using JSON if it's possible to model data using standard tables and columns - the queries probably become much simpler! (Got here while doing research on [JSON anti-patterns](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/json-postgresql-how-to-use-it-right/))